# Pandas - get list df columns names (e.g) in a string

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following dataframe

```
dtf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['howdy_dude'],
             'col2' : ["HI"],
             'col3' : ["3"]})
```

I need to get just the header columns with output in string format,
kind of : 'col1 + col2 + col3'

3 columns for this sample, but sometimes the number of columns can be higher, sometimes lower.

Thank you.

Comment: ','.join(list(dtf))

Comment: I'd start with dtf.columns

Comment: `dtf.columns.str.cat(sep=",")` ??

Comment: list(dtf) brings this result :['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

Comment: Thanks Anky_91. Works fine

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your question, you want sum of all column strings irrespective of the number of columns.

Here is response

```
dtf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['howdy_dude'],
             'col2' : ["HI"],
             'col3' : ["3"]})

dtf['new'] = dtf.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
dtf
```

This `new` column will have sum of all the strings in all the columns for the given row (you may remove space in join if you want).

[image]

And, if you want to add column names as string, you can use `join` as

```
dtf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['howdy_dude'],
             'col2' : ["HI"],
             'col3' : ["3"]})

result = " ".join(dtf.columns)
print (type(result))
result
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: You're giving the sum of the content of the columns. What I need is a string with the columns names 'col1 step col2 step col3' for instance

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho I have added, please let me know if this is what you are looking

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer is, as mentioned by [Harry_pb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987350/6734876):

```
" + ".join(dtf.columns)
```

Note that (`list()`) is useless.

---

However, it won't work if your column names are integers. You need to first convert them into strings, for example:

```
dtf.columns = [1,2,3]
" + ".join( dtf.columns.astype(str) )
```

Also, this method won't work if you have a `MultiIndex`. So in general, and it's quicker to write, you can do:

```
" + ".join( dtf.columns.format() )
```

---

If you need more control on the MultIndex format, I would use a list comprehension. For a fancy example:

```
id = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( (('A','X',0), ('B','Y',0), ('C','X',0)) )

'\n'.join([
    str(level) if i == 0 else '{}|_{}'.format('  '*(i-1), level)
    for elmt in id
    for i, level in enumerate(elmt)
])
```

Out:

```
A
|_X
  |_0
B
|_Y
  |_0
C
|_X
  |_0
```

Answer (score 0):

If specifically needed in this `'col1 + col2 + col3'`  format then,

```
"+".join(list(dtf.columns))
```

Answer (score -1):

to get all the columns use:

dtf.columns.tolist()

then you have a list of them and you can concatonate them as you like.

Comment: I understand, but dtf.columns.tolist() gives me the list of columns inside brackets.

Comment: Thanks anky. This works perfectly fine : dtf.columns.str.cat(sep=",")